# Laws are made for humans, but does everyone classify as a human?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-law, good-and-evil

By law, even the worst criminals may be pardoned on grounds of mercy etc. But if an animal attacks or even kills a human, it can be put down. My question is: Shouldn't there be 'rules' to determine who we can really call a human? That way, we could differentiate between when to attribute human rights and when not to.

NOTE: I'm only interested in discussing mental attributes of a human being, NOT physical ones.

Comment: Laws are made for persons, and yes, it is possible that not all humans are attributed personhood. You will find some answers and links here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personhood Please note that I edited your question; if you don't agree with my changes, you can use the rollback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are questioning is actually a *hotly* debated topic.  Different groups have *very* different opinions as to such definitions of words.  Your particular question is very apropos for the abortion debate going on in America today.  The debate *literally* boils down to a disagreement as to what is "human."

One solution is to have smoother laws without sharp edges between inanimate/wild-animal/pet/human.  However, writing such laws in a way that people find acceptable turns out to be a remarkable challenge, so we live with the fact that disagreement over the edges will be hotly debated in exchange for "something that doesn't spectacularly fail in every way."

If you are interested in a debate on what it means to "set rules to determine..." I highly recommend reading about [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems).  Many intuitively tempting phrasings for such rules fall into the sorts of First Order Logic structures Gödel was looking at.  He found such structures had some particularly nasty side effects which have profound implications on your question of "should we set rules..."

These implications are so profound that I would almost dare to answer your question with "no, we should not set such rules" simply because it is so hard for a layman (with less than a college math degree) to write rules which don't fall victim to the incompleteness theorems.  The only reason I would not answer "no" is because I think there are some *partial* rules which are beneficial, but sidestep Gödel's frustrating issues, and I think it can be good for society to seek those partial rules out.  They should just understand that any attempt to make those partial rules into complete rules is a very tricky business indeed.

Comment: This is a good answer except for the irrelevant stuff about the incompleteness theorem, which is just misleading.  It really doesn't matter at all whether laws are decidable; they're only supposed to work in the most obvious cases anyway, since surely you've forgotten to write down something important.

Comment: "They're only supposed to work in the obvious cases anyways" is a pretty contentious argument.  While I agree with you, and that's what I was getting towards with the idea of "partial rules," I find that the *vast* majority of Americans in particular have a fascination with the idea of rules which work perfectly in all cases.  I mention Godel because his theorem basically shuts down any shred of hope that such a perfect rule can be found, and that frees us to start looking for those rules which work in the most obvious cases.

Comment: That there is any room for precedent indicates that in practice decidability has often not been reached on a first pass, and given that precedent continues to grow around the same issue, it seems doubtful that successive passes are guaranteed perfect decidability either.  But you have made a very grand claim, without evidence, that it is actual _formal mathematical undecidability_ that has anything to do with the problem instead of more prosaic issues of imprecision of definition, difficulty of measurement, inherently subjective concerns, etc..

Comment: For evidence I might sight the public response to the Ferguson shooting.  There was a huge clamor to put rules in place to "prevent a shooting like Ferguson from ever occurring."  In every debate I faced with this, eventually somebody made a statement which was transformable to a statement that "we should find an axiomatic system with a particular set of properties" which fell into the class of problems Godel was looking at.  Every single one of the arguments brought forward was literally a search for something that was proven mathematically impossible decades ago.

Comment: For another point of evidence I came across the same pattern with abortion debates.  Every debate I came across which sought a legal rule-based solution to the problem fell afowl with Godel's incompleteness theorem, showing not only that there was a flaw with their particular solution, but that the entire class of solutions they were looking at were flawed.

Comment: I make a big deal about the use of Godel's incompleteness theorem because, entering every single debate, the other side acknowledged that "there were some details to be worked out," but was confident the details could be nailed down with a little more debate.  Godel was very helpful in showing that such an assumption was unfounded.

Comment: As more of an opinion, i have found that most of the places where Godel surprised people debating rules dealt with life-or-death issues.  Issues which are smaller than that, it seems to be reasonable to come up with rules.  Once death is part of the issue, there seems to be a strong tendency for rule based thinking to break down around incompleteness-related issues.  Given that the OP was explicitly talking about life-or-death examples, I felt Godel was worth mentioning.

Comment: Maybe chat is a better place for this, but you have only explained that you believe you found instances, not provided any evidence that incompleteness was actually pertinent.  Also, I think you may be mistaking rhetorical hyperbole ("never again") used to emphasize emotional commitment with a strong philosophical statement of possibility.

Comment: Perhaps, but none of those I debated with gave any indication that that was the case.  They seemed to truly believe that a rule was all that was needed.   Regardless, I didn't make the claim that "100% of rules don't work because of Godel," I claimed that "If you're looking into such rules, you should probably familiartize yourself with Godel."  Given that I found every debate on life-or-death topics I've had has ended with me winning via invoking Godel, it seemed like a reasonable addition to the answer (even if it is perhaps opinion based)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22380/discussion-between-cort-ammon-and-rex-kerr).

Comment: I do agree that such an attempt to make "rules" would be indeed tricky !